# Invertible Matrices as a Manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds

I've been trying to prove that the set of all invertible $n \times n$ matrices is a differentiable manifold. My attempt is as follows:

Define a map $\alpha : X \to XX^{-1} - I$
I take the inverse: $\alpha^{-1}(0)$ which would map to the set of invertible $n \times n$ matrices. I believe this suffices to show it is a manifold, but I am stumped in finding it's dimension. How can I approach this?

Comment: What is your domain of $\alpha$? And this map is just constant....

Comment: *Hint:*  first try to prove that $\Bbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ is a manifold without treating the two components separately.  (This is the $n=1$ case of your proposition.)

Comment: This has already been done [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175443/proving-that-the-general-linear-group-is-a-differentiable-manifold).

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate, and thanks for your hints. It turns out that with a bit of sleep I was able to get it :)